# How to remove vuetify file input clearable icon?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I do not find any props to inactive clearable icon. Also there has no event in this case. So is there any way to remove the clearable icon.

```
<v-file-input
  ref="profilePictureFileInput"
  v-model="profilePicture.file"
  :rules="profilePicture.rules"
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/jpg"
  placeholder="Pick an image"
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  append-inner-icon=""
  label="Image"
  clearable="false">
```

Comment: :clearable="false"

Answer (score 0):

Your binding on the `clearable` property is wrong. You need to use `:clearable="false"`. Right now, you are passing in the value as a string to the `<v-file-input>` component and you need to provide it a Boolean value.